# 'RestSharp.IRestResponse`1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp, sms-gateway, plivo

I am developing an app which requires SMS gateway service. Our company uses Plivo service. I followed along the [sample code](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-examples-dotnet/blob/master/PlivoMessage.cs).
When I tried to build solution I received two errors:

Error 1:`The type 'RestSharp.IRestResponse'1<T0>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'`

Error 2:`Cannot implicitly convert type 'RestSharp.IRestResponse'1<Plivo.API.MessageResponse>' to 'RestSharp.IRestResponse<Plivo.API.MessageResponse>'`

I don't get the reasons for these errors since I installed Plivo and RestSharp API's through NuGet and can see the dll's in Solution Explorer.
The second error is even more confusing to me because of the strange type `'RestSharp.IRestResponse'1`.

If anyone could advise me on this issues I'd be very grateful.

My source code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp;
using Plivo.API;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SMSGatewayTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string auth_id = "XXX";     // obtained from Plivo account dashboard
            string auth_token = "YYY";  // obtained from Plivo account dashboard

            RestAPI plivo = new RestAPI(auth_id, auth_token);

            IRestResponse<MessageResponse> resp = plivo.send_message(new Dictionary<string, string>() 
            {
                { "src", "37061549145" }, 
                { "dst", "37068824525" }, 
                { "text", "Hi, text from Plivo." }, 
            });


            if (resp.Data != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] proplist = resp.Data.GetType().GetProperties();
                foreach (PropertyInfo property in proplist)
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(resp.Data, null));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(resp.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. If I missed something while writing a question, please, ask for it - it's my first experience with SMS-gateway

Comment: `RestSharp.IRestResponse``1` is simply a generic type named `IRestResponse` with a single generic type argument. That's how it's named in IL - the equivalent in C# would be something like `IRestResponse<T>`.

Comment: @Luaan, thank you, that makes sense, though I still can't understand why compiler tries to convert smth, when according to API doc send_message() method has the same type.

Comment: Actually, the type name *is* suspicious - are you sure you copied it correctly? It should be `IRestResponse<Plivo.API.MessageResponse>` if C#, or `IRestResponse``1[System.String]`, but definitely not `IRestresponse'1<Plivo.API.MessageResponse>`. Are you sure you followed the installation instructions to the letter? What return type does VS show for the `plivo.send_message` method?

Comment: @Luaan, here is the screenshot from error log: http://postimg.org/image/co3hpsxr7/.
send_message return type: http://postimg.org/image/v1qd9vg5t/

Answer (score 2):

So after a few hours of investigating I managed to find out the case. It seems that automatic NuGet installation install RestSharp version 100.0.0, and you need 105.1.0.0. The solution was to enter the following in NuGet console:
Install-Package RestSharp -Version 105.0.1

Comment: i am having the same issue too. but when i tried the method suggested it did not work because nuget said no updates were available. The issue seems to be that Plivo version 2 package uses this a dependency. 

To fix it I reverted back to Plivo 1.3.7 which uses RestSharp 104.4 and it works

Comment: @TopDev we are having this issue too with 2.0.1 but working fine on 1.3.7, do you happen to be using mono?

Comment: I just tried v2.0.0 and it works fine, seems like the issue is that the RestSharp dependency is not configured correct in the nuget package. I've logged the issue here: https://github.com/plivo/plivo-dotnet/issues/25